# issue with ajax pagination in bootstrap tab on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

This is my code so i tried using jquery html load but nothing happens need help masters so any help from you guyz would be appreciated so it would be easy if you guyz would help me to have ajax pagination in my bootstrap navigation.

```
<?php
    /*
     * Template Name: Gallery
     */
    get_header(); ?>
     <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">




     </script>
        <div class="about-content">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="border-bottom">
                        <!--images-->
                <div class="services images">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="images-tab" role="tabpanel">
                              <!-- Nav tabs -->
                              <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                                <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#all" aria-controls="all" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">VIEW ALL</a></li>
                                <?php $args =  array('hide_empty' => false);
                                                            $image_category = get_terms('image_category',$args);
                                                            foreach($image_category as $image_categories ) :?>
                                                        <li role="presentation"><a href="#<?php echo $image_categories->slug ?>" aria-controls="<?php echo $image_categories->slug ?>" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $image_categories->name; ?></a></li>
                              <?php endforeach;wp_reset_query(); ?>  
                                                      </ul>

                              <!-- Tab panes -->
                              <div class="tab-content">
                            <?php
                                                             $args =  array('hide_empty' => false);
                                                            $image_category = get_terms('image_category',$args);
                                                            foreach($image_category as $image_categories ) :?>
                                                            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="<?php echo $image_categories->slug; ?>">
                                                           <div class="row" id="content">
                                                                <?php 
                                                                 $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

                                                                 $arg = array(
                                                                    'post_type' => 'gallery',
                                                                     'posts_per_page' =>1,
                                                                     'paged' => $paged,
                                                                    'tax_query' => array(
                                                                        array(
                                                                                'taxonomy' => 'image_category',
                                                                                'field' => 'name',
                                                                                'terms' => $image_categories
                                                                        )
                                                                        )
                                                               );
                                                    $query = new WP_Query($arg);
                                                    while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
                                                    $args1 = array('orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC', 'fields' => 'all');
                                                    $category_object = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID,'image_category',$args1); ?> 






                                    <div id="content" class="post col-md-4"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>



                                <?php  endwhile;  wp_reset_postdata();?>
                                                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                                          <?php endforeach; ?>
                              </div>

                            </div>


                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <!--images-->

                    <div class="pagination-content">

                            <ul>
                                <li><i class="fa fa-play fa-rotate-180"></i></li>

                                                            <li>                                                                                            <?php
    global $wp_query;

    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
    //$translated = __( 'Page', 'mytextdomain' ); // Supply translatable string

    echo paginate_links( array(
        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'prev_next' => false,
        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
        'total' => $query->max_num_pages,
            //'before_page_number' => '<span class="screen-reader-text">'.$translated.' </span>'
    ) );
    ?></li>

                                <li class="yellow"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></a></li>                      
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of ajax wp pagination plugin you can use those https://www.designmaz.net/best-wordpress-pagination-plugins/